# Gulp module that can extract <script> (or <style>) tags into a new separate file

Tags: javascript, html, module, gulp

Is there a gulp module that can extract `<script>` (or `<style>`) tags into a separate file?

For example:

#### Original HTML file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            .my-style{
                background:red;
            }
        </style>

        <div class="my-style">
            hello
        </div>

        <script>
            var MyScript = function(){
                console.log("hello");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### new HTML file

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="my-style">
            hello
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### new CSS file

```
.my-style{
    background:red;
}
```

#### new JS file

```
var MyScript = function(){
    console.log("hello");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To extract inline scripts to external .js file you can use can use Cripser - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-crisper

```
.pipe(crisper({
      scriptInHead: true,
      onlySplit: false
    }))
```

While I couldn't find anything that extracts inline CSS to external file, you can at least minify the inline CSS using 'gulp-minify-inline' which is alternative option - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-inline

Answer (score 1):

Try gulp-html-extract https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-extract even though it looks unmaintained and probably you can use concat or rename to create the final file.