# Combining Relative Files in Gulp

Tags: html, css, gulp

I need to combine some HTML files with the CSS that resides in the same directory using Gulp. The file structure of my project is as follows.

```
- src
    - dir1
        - index.html
        - style.css
    - dir2
        - index.html
        - style.css
    - dir3
        - index.html
        - style.css
```

So, I'm combining the HTML and CSS from dir1, then the HTML and CSS from dir2, and so on.

I've tried to do this several ways (including the following) but can't get anything to work the way I want.

```
.pipe(replace('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">', function (match, p1) {
    return '<style>' + fs.readFileSync('src/' + p1, 'utf8') + '</style>';
}))
```

Is there an easy way to reference relative files in Gulp?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using gulp 4 and gulp-replace, and that your gulpfile.js is located in the project directory, next to the src subdirectory.

Then the task consists of three steps:

1. read the index.html files
2. replace the string `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` with a `<style>` tag with the contents of the file style.css in the same directory as index.html.
3. write the changed index.html files to a new destination directory.

Steps 1 and 3 are easy to accomplish with `gulp.src` and `gulp.dist`, so let's look at step 2. Each style.css (the file we want to read) resides in the same directory as index.html. That directory can be retrieved with `this.file.dirname` in the gulp-replace callback. If we append "style.css" to that directory, we will get a full path to a CSS file that can be read with `readFileSync`. The rest is pretty straightforward:

```js
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const { join } = require('path');

exports.default = () =>
    gulp.src('src/**/index.html')
    .pipe(replace('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">', function () {
        const stylePath = join(this.file.dirname, 'style.css');
        const style = readFileSync(stylePath);
        return `<style>${style}</style>`;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
```

I really think that the only unobvious part in this process is getting the directory of each index.html/style.css file pair in the gulp-replace callback as `this.file.dirname`. Here, according to [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace):

> The value of `this.file` will be equal to the [vinyl instance](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#instance-properties) for the file being processed.

and [`file.dirname`](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#filedirname) for a vinyl file

> Gets and sets the dirname of `file.path`. Will always be normalized and have trailing separators removed.

Comment: perfect! could we revert that also ? - extracting scripts or styles from html to a separate file

Comment: @Abd-ElazizSharaf About reversing the process, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31501877/gulp-module-that-can-extract-script-or-style-tags-into-a-new-separate-file). But if your use case is different you could ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a huge help. For a bonus point, do you know how I can purify the CSS, using something like uncss (link below) before combining it with the HTML?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss

Comment: That's it, Thanks @GOTO0

Comment: @Ben Happy to help. Unfortunately, I've never worked with uncss, so I'll have to skip the bonus points this time :/ Anyway, it seems that gulp-uncss is deprecated in favor of [gulp-postcss](https://github.com/postcss/gulp-postcss), and postcss has [a plugin](https://github.com/gucong3000/postcss-html) to process CSS inside HTML files, so maybe it could help. Well, at least I would try with that one first.

Comment: All good, @GOTO 0. I did a bit of reading and managed to come up with something that works. It's not the most elegant solution but it does the job, and I guess I can refine it over time!